# Building API - safe way to send password

Tags: security, rest, restful-authentication

I'm building a REST API and I am in doubt about the way the password's sent is safe?

The password is sent in the URL like this:

```
https://www.example.com/api-version/user-name/password/
```

Answer (score 4):

Send it in POST payload (not in URL!) over SSL encrypted connection. Sending password as you suggested is extremely insecure.

Comment: I know it's better to send it in a POST payload (and more restful too), but I don't think sending a password in an URL *when using SSL*, is insecure, since the URL gets encrypted too, right?

Comment: If accessed through a browser the passwords will pop up in the browser history. Also the passwords will be left in proxies etc.

Comment: I don't think that password will be left in proxies (cause whole communication is encrypted) but certainly it will stay in the browser history.

Comment: isn't the query too left in the browser history?

Comment: Yes, it is visible in for example Chrome developer tools or Mozilla FireBug, but it's not as much visible as entries in the web browser history. First of all, you have to activate such tool in order to record traffic and secondly it's not stored such a long time as in the web browser history (close web browser, and firebug requests history disappears).

Answer (score 3):

Yeah. Don't do that. Either use [HTTP Basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), or pass an access token such as an OAuth token as a parameter, i.e.

`http://www.example.com/api-version/end-point/?access_token=...`

Comment: Even sending an `access_token` or using HTTP Basic Auth is insecure when you aren't using SSL, it's still vulnerable for MITM-attacks.

Comment: It's better than dropping it in the URL; and if it's good enough for sites like Twitter and Facebook then it's good enough for "normal" websites and web apps. I don't think there's one bulletproof way of transmitting data from one machine to another without it being intercepted somehow if someone really wants to get at it.