# Identity server 3, is it possible to have an api endpoint to get access tokens

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, identity, identityserver3

We have an api that offloads authentication to an implementation of identity server 3. When a user uses our application they are directed to Identity server to authenticate, with either username and password or an AD

For our functional tests we need to be able to authenticate with the api, is there a way to authenticate with id server via a REST endpoint rather than being directed to a webpage and/or a callback url?

Ideally we would like to hit an endpoint the id server application (with username, password, scopes etc) and it return us a json body with our access token.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have found a way. To get around this we have created a new client only for our test environment that has a client resource type of resource. This enables authentication without user input, (where using our own credentials rather than third party)

Answer (score 0):

Identity Server 3 doesn't do this, mainly because it's a bad idea to send passwords.  [see also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7257889/building-api-safe-way-to-send-password)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the question is to test an API that expects a token in its header and how to get that token to test that api. If i get that right, see below.

I used Postman to test our API. Postman has ability to do that.

Follow the below steps

1. Post man goto Authorize tab and in type select Oauth2.0

[image]

2.click Get new access token button and fill up the details

[image]

as you said its identityserver 3 token name is "any name you want" 
auth url is your "https://servername/connect/authorize"
AccessToken Url is "https:servername/connect/token"
Clientid is your clientid
secret is secret of your clientid
Scope is your scope
Granttype is Authorization code.

Then click "request token" button you will be prompted to enter username and password. Make sure to add "https://www.getpostman.com/oauth2/callback" in your database under table clientredireturi.

[image]

under existing tokens you will see the name that you gave in token textbox. click on it and it will show you the token. Choose Add token to to header from dropdown and click on use token button it will be added to the headers of your end point that you are trying to test.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed post. It’s the human interaction we are trying to avoid. We want our functional tests, test that physically hit our api to authenticate without human interaction.